# Shopware 6: add custom rule for real new users including guests

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

i would like to create a promotion for the shipping costs that is valid for every new customer. obviously there is no rule that checks if a customer has already placed an order with his e-mail address.
i can only check the number of orders for registered customers, but not for guest customers.
i would like to add a custom rule for this, but i don't know exactly how to query the email address of the guest customer. moreover, this note is in the documentation:
*Never execute database queries or any other time-consuming operations within the match() method of your rule, as it will drastically impact the performance of your store. *

how can i query at this point whether this email address has already been used?

i have read the documentation and can basically add a custom rule. but i can't figure out how to query the email address of guest customers with the database.

thanks in advance